# Java / SQL Server 2008 R2 Express connection issues

Tags: java, sql-server, sql-server-2008, jdbc

I'm trying to connect to a SQL Server db on my local machine using the following code:

```
import java.sql.*;
import com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.*;
import java.sql.*;


public class JDBConn {

    //public class connectURL {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // Declare the JDBC objects.
            Connection con = null;
            Statement stmt = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;

            // Create a variable for the connection string.

            //String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;database=optRes1;integratedSecurity=true;";
            //con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);



                try {
                    // Establish the connection.
                    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
                    String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost";
                    con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
                    Statement s = con.createStatement();
                    ResultSet r = s.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM some_table_name");
                    while (r.next()) {
                        System.out.println(r.getString(1));
                    }


                        // Create and execute an SQL statement that returns some data.
                        String SQL = "SELECT * from [optRes1].[dbo].[unEmpDat]";
                        stmt = con.createStatement();
                        rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);

                        // Iterate through the data in the result set and display it.
                        while (rs.next()) {
                            System.out.println(rs.getString(4) + " " + rs.getString(6));
                        }
                }

            // Handle any errors that may have occurred.
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            finally {
                if (rs != null) try { rs.close(); } catch(Exception e) {}
                    if (stmt != null) try { stmt.close(); } catch(Exception e) {}
                    if (con != null) try { con.close(); } catch(Exception e) {}
            }
        }
}
```

I'm getting the following message when I try to connect (I'm using Eclipse as an IDE):

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connection refused: connect. Verify the connection properties, check that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port, and that no firewall is blocking TCP connections to the port.".
```

So far, I've gone into the Configuration Mgr and activated and enabled TCP/IP.

I've also gone in and set each IP address to on and active under the Properties > IP Addresses tab.

A couple of potential issues.

When I look at the status of the SQL Server Browser it is 'Stopped'.  I'm not sure if this is an issue and if so how to fix it.

I'm using the `sqljdbc4.jar` file and have it in the Referenced Libraries section of the project.

Let me know if you have any suggestions please.

EDIT:

I'm using a Windows 7 box.

UPDATE:

```
>java -version
java version "1.6.0_14"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_14-b08)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.0-b16, mixed mode)
```

Comment: SQL Server **Browser** is not required to be running. But with JDBC connections it's easier if you turn off SQL Server dynamic ports and force all network interfaces to use port 1433 via the SQL Server Configuration application.

Comment: I needed to restart the server and turn on error logging.  The window to restart the server was hidden behind some other windows and didn't see it.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't include which JRE version you are using, but there is a known issue between 1.6.0_29 and SQL Server 2008 documented in [Bug ID 7105007](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7105007) There's also a [thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqldataaccess/thread/97dce8fd-6487-4bca-80b0-492167db3e0d) in the Microsoft forums too which suggests downgrading to 1.6.0_27.

You can also just replace _29's `jsse.jar` with the one from _27. This is mostly useful for Mac OS clients where it's difficult to downgrade. Target file is `Mac HD -> System -> Library -> Java -> JavaVirtualMachines -> 1.6.0.jdk -> Contents -> Classes -> jsse.jar`